# Mobx(4.0.1) and mobx-state-tree(1.3.1) not compatible

Tags: javascript, npm, mobx, mobx-react, mobx-state-tree

- OS - Windows 10 x64
- NodeJs v8.9.3
- npm 5.7.1

repository for sample code - https://github.com/niral3737/testMobxStateTreeApp

I am working with mobx-state-tree and I have created a model Invoice with a field name.
I am using that model in App.js class.

When it compiles, it throws

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/mobx-state-tree/dist/mobx-state-tree.module.js
2247:12-18 'mobx' does not contain an export named 'extras'.
```

what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

> warning " > mobx-state-tree@1.4.0" has incorrect peer dependency "mobx@^3.1.15".

Drop your dependencies down to:

> "dependencies": {
>       "mobx": "3.1.15",

..and away you go!

P.S. Always use Yarn, when developing in React.JS and always run:

> Yarn check

..before you commence with development.